# Unidentified index error, No results in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have tried figuring out what the issue is for 3 days now and I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have creating a website which involves a 'register' page. 
I have also set up a database via MySQL Workbench and it seems to be fully connected to my website (according to PhpStorm).

issue is, once i fill in the registration details on the page, i get hit with this error **which points to my SQL query...**

> **"Notice: Undefined index: first_name in F:\Client Server**
>   **Side\MVCtemplate\Models\userDataSet.php on line 20"** etc..

userDataSet.php code:

```
<?php

require_once ('Models/Database.php');
require_once ('Models/userData.php');

class userDataSet
{
    protected $_dbHandle, $_dbInstance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_dbInstance = Database::getInstance();
        $this->_dbHandle = $this->_dbInstance->getdbConnection();

    }

    public function registerUser()
    {

            $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO accounts (first_name, last_name, u_name, u_email, u_password, c_password) 
        VALUES ('" . $_POST["first_name"] . "','" . $_POST["last_name"] . "','" . $_POST["u_name"] . "','" . $_POST["u_email"] . "','" . $_POST["u_password"] . "','" . $_POST["c_password"] . "')";


        $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $statement->execute();

        $dataSet = [];
        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
            $dataSet[] = new userData($row);
        }
        return $dataSet;
    }
}
```

Also get the same error with my "userData.php" page which points to this:

```
    $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
    $u_name = $_POST["u_name"];
    $u_email = $_POST["u_email"];
    $u_password = $_POST["u_password"];
    $c_password = $_POST["c_password"];


    $dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);

    $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO accounts (first_name, last_name, u_name, u_email, u_password, c_password)
    VALUES ('$first_name, $last_name, $u_name, $u_email, $u_password, $c_password')";

    $statement = $dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); //prepare PDO statement
    $statement->execute();
```

register form code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name"
                                       placeholder="Enter your Name"/>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="form-group ">
                    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button">Register
                    </button>
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'></p>"; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: You should check the tables, for errors, because the rror message point to that. But when you use prepare statement, please also use bindparameter, because this would still be unsecure.

Comment: What exactly is in "line 20"? I guess the `$_POST` array doesn't contain `first_name`. Check the content with `var_dump($_POST)`. Then check your HTML form.

Comment: Also see: [how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined) and [cargo_cult_prepared_statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement)

Comment: Where is your 'register' page code? the problem lies in there.

Answer (score -1):

The error is due to the HTML form you are submitting to the script, which does not contain an input with the `name` attribute `first_name`.

Your code is also very insecure as it is open to SQL injection, FYI.

It is also possible your `<form method` is not set to `POST`

Comment: I have the correct attribute and form method.

Comment: Please post the code for your form, the issue is certainly caused there

Comment: i have posted my register form code.

Comment: is that the whole thing? where's the submit element and the closing </form> tag?

Comment: its pretty long hence why i just shown the form attributes.

Comment: I have posted the submit element now.

Comment: I agree there are no issues with the snippet you have shown, but I am still convinced the error lies in your form. Have you tried looking at the data that gets submitted in the Network section of your browser's developer tools?